# How to check if a large binary file contains the contents of another one?

Tags: c, file

the files are getting from the main argv i got one big binary file of an image and I'm trying to compare it to a small file that contains a certain text in the big file
I tried to get the data from the big file and from the little file but i don't know how to compare between them

this is what I wrote so far:

````
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* virusSign = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) * sizeof(char));
    FILE* inp;
    FILE* data;
    FILE* logAnswer;
    FILE* virusSign;
    logAnswer = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    data = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    printf("Welcome to my virus scanner!!\n");
    switch (argc) 
    {
    case 3:
        inp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        virusSign = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
        if (virusSign == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'\n", argv[2]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (inp == NULL) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("you were asked to put a folder and a virus sign");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //getting the files data
    data_getter(inp, data);
    if (virusChecker(virusSign, data))
    {
        fputs();
    }
    fclose(data);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}```
````

Comment: Use `memcmp` with the size and content of the signature on every possible position in the file you want to check.

Comment: `Could not open file '%s'` is a useless error message.  Provide a reason.  eg: `if( (virusSign = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) == NULL ){ perror(argv[2]); ...`

Comment: Sorry, your program doesn't compile: read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your snippet to create a compilable and testable sample of code, so we don't need to modify it to make a diagnostic. If we need to modify your code to test it, we can repair the problem that affects you and make your post hopeless.  Correct the compilation errors and repost.  Post also, if possible, what you expect from the program, and what you actually get from it.  Procure to post a program that you have compiled and shows the error.